# How to use a custom Dialog in kotlin

Tags: android, dialog, retrofit2, response

I have this small class that i want use to show and close my dialog, my retrofit reponse is loading the list of items

```
class ShowProgress(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {

var dialog = Dialog(context)

fun showDialog() {
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout)
    dialog.show()
}

fun closeDialog() {
    dialog.dismiss()
}
}
```

Im getting the dialog to show up but it wont dismiss() when the response is complete. What whould be the issue here exactly?

Comment: Can you show complete code ?

Comment: how much of the code do you want see because its this class then a fragment thats gets a retrofit response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how you can show and dismiss custom popup;

```
class ShowProgress(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {

    init {
        dialog = Dialog(context)
    }

    fun showPopup() {

        val dialogview = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog_choose_image, null, false)
        //initializing dialog screen

        dialog?.setCancelable(true)
        dialog?.setContentView(dialogview)
        dialog?.show()

    }
    companion object{
        var dialog: Dialog? = null
        fun dismissPopup() = dialog?.let { dialog!!.dismiss() }
    }

}
```

and from view you can access it like this.
`val showProgress = ShowProgress(this) showProgress.showPopup()`

and dismiss it whenever you want to dismiss popup
`ShowProgress.dismissPopup()`

Comment: I understand the showpopup, but how do i get the dissmisspopup to work. its not very clear how you reach the dialog object from that method

Comment: I have edited the answer. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Well it Behaves the same way like it did before

Comment: Hmm... No problem buddy.